# Write unit test for okhttp timeout

Tags: android, junit4, okhttp, powermockito, mockserver

I have written test case for okHttp **SocketTimeoutException** like this:

```
    @Test
    public void contactDetailsTimeOut() throws Exception {
    server.enqueue(new MockResponse().setBody("{}").setBodyDelay(31, TimeUnit.SECONDS));

    HttpUrl baseUrl = server.url("/v1/contact/");
    userProfilePresenter.contactDetails(baseUrl.toString());
    verify(userProfileView).error(isA(SocketTimeoutException.class), isA(String.class));
    }
```

Same can be achieved by setting **setSocketPolicy** to **SocketPolicy.NO_RESPONSE**

```
    @Test
    public void contactDetailsTimeOut() throws Exception {
    server.enqueue(new MockResponse().setBody("{}").setSocketPolicy(SocketPolicy.NO_RESPONSE));

    HttpUrl baseUrl = server.url("/v1/contact/");
    userProfilePresenter.contactDetails(baseUrl.toString());
    verify(userProfileView).error(isA(SocketTimeoutException.class), isA(String.class));
    }
```

As i have set okHttp **readTimeout** to 30 sec. This test case wait for 30 sec to pass. Expected behaviour. Below is the code of okHttpClient

```
private static OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();
```

My question is: **Is there any way i can test SocketTimeoutException in less time? I do not want to reduce timing from client side.**

Comment: Any luck testing this in less time?

Comment: @StuStirling no, i just comment this and testing it manually when required.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom OkHttpClient in singleton pattern, and then you can prepare it in the setup() in unit test.